# What is the significance of a Lagrangian Submanifold and what are the implications of the symplectic form being zero?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, lagrangian-submanifolds

I'd like to understand better the relevance of Lagrangian submanifolds in Hamiltonian Mechanics. A Lagrangian Manifold is defined as a submanifold of a symplectic manifold upon which the restriction of a symplectic form $\omega$ is vanishing. I'd like to understand what this property means and how the flow of a Lagrangian submanifold differs from that of an arbitrary submanifold.

To summarise:

- What does the condition of vanishing symplectic for imply on a Lagrangian Manifold?
- What make Lagrangian submanifold different to other submanifolds in the context of Hamiltonian Mechanics?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Take a section $s:M\to T^*M$ of the cotangent bundle  of a smooth manifold $M$, i.e., a $1$-form . The image $s(M)$ is a submanifold of $T^*M$ of dimension $\dim M$. It is Lagrangian iff  $s$ is a closed form.   In particular, if $M$ is imply connected, this means that $s$ is  the differential of a smooth function. For more look at Arnold's *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics*

Comment: If you're interested in solving Hamilton's equations with boundary conditions (like fixing initial and final position) then having Lagrangian boundary conditions ensures the trajectories are critical points of the symplectic action functional. I've written a blog post about this (as an introduction to Floer theory) here: http://www.jde27.uk/blog/fukaya1.html